# choosing between single backend/frontend project and separate backend and frontend projects

Tags: frontend, backend

I saw the approach where the frontend and backend applications are located in the single project and the frontend application generates `bundle.js` that is used in `index.html` served by backend controller.

I also saw an approach where frontend and backend applications were completely separate projects and frontend knows the endpoint of the backend running separately.

Which approach is better? What should be considered between choosing one approach or another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have two approaches as you have mentioned

1. The front end and the backend in a same project.
2. The front end and the backend in a different project.

I would like to highlight the differences for both

For the point 1 Its suitable where

1. You have small scale projects.
2. Where everything can be managed in the same project like not too much of backend is needed in terms of maintainibilty.
3. If the there is a single front end using a single backend project.

Will elaborate the third point like consider if you have different front end projects communicating with the same backend.

And the main point is you want to expose your apis publicly then its not recommended for the first approach

The 2 approach is something

Where you write sharable apis , maintaibility is needed across the teams too much of backend is required and maintained time to time etc... For example like microservices architecture....!!!